# Contar quantas databases existem

Tags: php, mysql

No sistema que estou montando, na dashboard do adm mostra o total de pedidos, que nos quais são criadas databases para cada usuário e dentro delas, registrados os pedidos pelas tables.

Ex: Usuário 75, tem sua db `pedidos_75` e dentro tem as tabelas com as IDs de cada pedido.

A pergunta é, tem como fazer uma seleção de databases e contar quantas tem com o nome começando por `pedidos`, como se fosse um `SHOW TABLES LIKE "pedidos%"` e `count`?

Answer (score 1):

Tentar fazer assim:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'nomeDoBanco' and TABLE_NAME like '%pedidos%';
```

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda cara, mas decidi criar uma tabela e fazer implementação de alguns dados que iriam precisar em outras áreas do painel também.